# GCP SSH keys add in console gives sudo user access, how can we avoid it?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, google-cloud-platform

There are two answers to my questions one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31012260/11748994) and the other one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31602378/11748994). None of them answers my question. In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72355933/11748994) @John Hanley suggested me to add a user and put the public key manually in `.ssh/authorized_keys` which is a desired method for me because I want to add users and send them a private key so that they can ssh to the server and do their parts. But when I use this method and try to `ssh` using this new user, I get `Permission denied (publickey)`.

The following is my question:

I have created 3 `ssh` key pairs for three users and they can `ssh` to a VM that is in on one of my projects on GCP. These keys have been added to the VM via console.
The problem is that all of these users have sudo access because when I execute the following it tells that they have all accesses they want:

```
sudo -l -U user

Matching Defaults entries for user on project:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User user may run the following commands on project:
    (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

How can I restrict their access to an ordinary user? Or how can I avoid this problem from the beggining.

This is how I created my keys:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f {path}\{key-name} -C {user-name}
```

Then, I copied the public key and added to `ssh keys` in console.

Comment: How are you creating the users? If your users are being automatically added to group `google-sudoers`, then check out the answer here for some solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62642813/7411885 - if not, then investigate the sudoers configuration

Comment: @Cpt.Whale: As I explained in the statement I use `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f {path}\{key-name} -C {user-name}` to create a key for a user and then put the public key on the `ssk key` section of the console. In this way, these users get added to `google-sudoers`. Also, I do not see these users in IAM and I can see them by `sudo cat /etc/group` on the server.

Comment: Your SSH stuff is working fine. Where do the user accounts come from - google user accounts or a manual `useradd` on the VM? non-privileged google users requires configuring OS Login roles like in the linked answer, while manually created users shouldn't get added to sudoers by default at all

Comment: @Cpt.Whale: as I explain in the statement, `google-sudousers` are the ones that I have added a public key on the GCP console. When, I use `useradd` to create a new user. That cannot `ssh`. Could you please read my statement and let me know which part is unclear because I am writing parts of the question statement as comments.

Comment: What is the path you placed the keys into for users created with `useradd`, `/home/user-name/.ssh/authorized_keys`? And did you set permissions on the key to the user like `chown username:username /path/to/keys` and `chmod 600 /path/to/keys`?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale: I used my username `owner` and added the created key for the user created by `useradd` to `/home/owner/.ssh/authorized_keys` and paste it next to `owner` public key. Did I do it right? However, I did not set permissions on the key. I am confused if all of these should happen in `/home/owner/.ssh/authorized_keys` or I have to use `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Comment: If a key belongs to user01, then it needs to go into `/home/user01/.ssh/authorized_keys`. It cannot just go into a new line in `owner`'s keys for example. For new local users, this usually creates a new file, which might need permissions assigned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136554/discussion-between-sepide-and-cpt-whale).

Comment: @Cpt.Whale: please check the chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a generated public key on GCP console, you create a user that gets added to `google-sudoers`. You can see it by `$cat /etc/group`. If you want to hire a contractor or create a user who does not have `sudo` privilege you need to do the following:

1. Switch to `root` from a user that has `sudo` privilage: `sudo -s`
2. Create a user: `useradd user1` and `sudo mkhomedir_helper user1` or in one shot `sudo useradd -m username` that creates the user `user1` and its home directory.
3. Create `.ssh` folder and `authorized_keys` inside of the `.ssh` folder.
4. Change the owener of the `.ssh` folder to `user1`: `chown -R user1:user1 user1/.ssh`
5. Change the mode of the `authorized_keys` file to 600: `chmod 600 user/.ssh/authorized_keys`
6. Paste the public key associated with `user1` inside `authorized_keys`.
7. `ssh` to the server: `ssh -i {path}\private_key_name user1@machine_ip`